# Focus on TextField not working when button pressed in Dialog - Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My goal is to set focus on a Material UI TextField after closing a Dialog by clicking a button in this Dialog.

The following piece of code works when I call it from a button that is not in a dialog component:

```
focusTitle = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  this.myRef.current.focus();
};
```

Code of button:

```
<Button onClick={this.focusTitle} />
```

Code of textfield I want to focus on:

```
<TextField
  inputRef={this.myRef}
  label="Title"
  id="title"
  multiline
  rowsMax="4"
  value={this.state.title}
  autoFocus={true}
  className={classes.title}
  helperText="Enter a catchy title"
  onChange={e => this.onTitleChange(e.target.value)}
/>
```

But as soon as I try to call the focusTitle() from a button within a dialog it does not trigger the focus.

Code of dialog:

```
<Dialog
  open={this.state.isOpen}
  onClose={this.focusTitle}
  aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
  aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
  >

  <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Warning"}</DialogTitle>

  <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
      Warning Message!
    </DialogContentText>
  </DialogContent>

  <DialogActions>
    <Button onClick={this.focusTitle} color="primary">
      OK
    </Button>
  </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Anyone has an idea why my .focus() is not working in the case of the dialog? If I log this.refs.myRef in both cases it shows the exact same result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dialog probably has a closing animation. As long as the animation is running, the `focus()` function will not be called correctly.

To prevent this, create a callback for the animation or a timeout for the duration of the animation, to trigger the `focus()` afterwards. Like this:

```
focusTitle = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      this.myRef.current.focus();
     }
    .bind(this),
    500 // Change to duration of the animation
};
```